# Method for computing limit of a sin function as x tends to zero

Tags: limits, functions, infinity

I have a question about computing 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} \sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{4|x|}\right)$$
I found the limit of $\pi x$ and $4|x|$ seperately and ended with $\sin(\pi/4)$ which is equal to $1/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Is the function $\sin\left(\dfrac{\pi x}{4|x|}\right)$? Also, is the limit as $x \to 0^+$ (just from the right) or as $x \to 0$ (from both the left and the right)?

Comment: the limit is as x tends to 0 from both left and right

Comment: $\sin ({ \pi \over 4} { x \over |x|}) = \operatorname{sgn} x \sin { \pi \over 4}$. Hence no limit exists.

Comment: could the same be said for a cosine variation?

Comment: Well, $\cos$ is even, so the limit exists in this case, and is $\cos { \pi \over 4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi x}{4 |x|} \right )$ exists only if *both* the limit from the left and from the right exist as well.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi x}{4 |x|} \right ) = \lim_{x \to 0^{-}} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi x}{-4x} \right ) = -\sin \left ( \frac \pi 4 \right )$$

$$\lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi x}{4 |x|} \right ) = \lim_{x \to 0^{+}} \sin \left ( \frac{\pi x}{4x} \right ) = \sin \left (\frac \pi 4 \right )$$

Hence the limit does not exist.

Regarding your cosine variation: $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to 0} \cos \left ( \frac{\pi x}{4 |x|} \right )$ exists because $\cos$ is an even function and therefore you have $\cos(-x) = \cos(x)$. In this case then the limit is $\displaystyle\cos \frac \pi 4 = \frac 1 {\sqrt{2}}$.